# Running multiple httpServer in one Node Process or each server in own node process

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, ports

I'm trying to figure out what's the better solution.

I am running two http servers in my node app, server 1 at port 3000, server 2 on port 3001. Server 1 is making the main logic and database handling, while server 2 handles the file requests.

When I start my app with node myApp.js both servers are launched and listening to their ports.

```
/*
 *Fire Up the Servers
 */
http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('HTTP Express server listening on port 3000');
});

http.createServer(fileserver).listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('HTTP Fileserver is listening on port 3001');
});
```

Now my Question: Does anyone know if it would make any difference if I would write for every server an own node process, so that I have to run *node myApp.js* which launches server 1, listening on port 3000 and then run *node myFileserver.js* which listens on port 3001.

Is there any performance difference?
Or any hints where I can read something about it?

Regards, 
Martin

Comment: These sound like two separate applications. I don't think you should write them together to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the rest of the code. If both the servers have shared states it's better to start them in same process.

If there is no shared state it's better to have them in separate processes so that one's execution flow does not affect the number of requests server by the other one. Specially true if one is IO bound and the other one is cpu intensive.

Also if you are starting them in the same process why not do both the things on the same port?

Comment: Thanks! I have separate ports, because they use separate domains. The fileserver on port 3001 handles requests like files.mydomain.com. The other server on port 3000 answers requests for domain mydomain.com. I have a proxy (Node.js proxy server) in front of both that handles the header requests and shifts them to the appropriate port where the specific server is listening. I do this, because I want to be more flexible with my files and get a better performance, because once I had both on one server and one port, I realized some negative effects on my app during file-serving.

Comment: What do you mean by shared states? I think they don't have.

Comment: Shared state mean are there variables which are used by both the routes?

Comment: If they are on separate domains then you should surely go for separate processes. There is a very small overhead of the separate process but result is very clean separation of concerns.

Comment: Ok, thanks. No are no variables shared. They run completely separate. I just tried it now and run two separate processes. Code gets cleaner of course, and I think the performance is a bit better, but that is only subjective and I cant proof that.